# Correctness of Proof that the limit of $\sqrt n\cdot c^n$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

The problem is: Given that $|c|<1$ prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n \cdot c^n =0$. I am asked to use the comparison lemma and archimedean property to show convergence for sequence $\{1/\sqrt n\}$

Proof:
Assume $|c|<1$.
We can also assume that $c$ can be expressed as $1/1+d$, $d>0$, and by using binomial formula,

$$ |c^n| \leq 1/1+nd \leq 1/dn$$

By definition of limit convergence $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n \cdot c^n =0$ means for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N |\sqrt n \cdot c^n-0|<\epsilon$.
In other words we must pick an $N$ s.t. $\sqrt n \cdot c^n<\epsilon$ for if $n \geq N$
This means

$$ \sqrt n \cdot c^n \leq \sqrt n \cdot (1/1+d)^n \leq (1/dn)\cdot\sqrt n \leq 1/\sqrt n \leq 1/n \leq 1/N < \epsilon $$

for all $n \geq N$

So $\sqrt n \cdot c^n$ converges to 0 and the required inequality holds for this $N$.

Comment: **Nitpick:** You have chosen $N$ to be such that $ N \ge \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} $ which you must clearly mention and a word as to why such an $N$ exists must also be put out there in my opinion if you are a beginner. Otherwise the proof is alright.

Comment: Actually one of my errors here is that $$ 1/\sqrt n \leq 1/n$$...need to fix that.

Comment: @Ishfaaq you can easily do that via the ARchmidean property